# tensorflow import bug: No module named 'tensorflow.python.eager.polymorphic_function'

Tags: tensorflow, import, importerror, modulenotfounderror

[image]I am trying to import the tensorflow module in my jupyter notebook, however this error appears. I have imported ternsorflow before, therefore I am not cure why it is showing the error: **`ModuleNotFoundError`**`: No module named 'tensorflow.python.eager.polymorphic_function'` . Could someone help me fix this?

I tried checking if tensorflow is installed, and indeed it is.

Comment: Please follow the step by step instructions mentioned in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) to install tensorflow in your system. Let us know If the issue still persists with some more details like -  which `OS`, `Python` , `Tensorflow version` you are using and what are all the steps you have followed to install the Tensorflow in your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have two (or more) Python interpreters installed, and used pip to install in one of them and then tried to run the other.

please run these commands at the shell :

```
pip -V
which python
```

Once you get the version, download the latest Python and **Add it to your PATH variable**

Also, you need not install Tensorflow multiple times resulting in creating several conda environments.

run this following command in a new environment :

```
python -m pip install tensorflow
```

This should get the boat sailing.